# How to peek into the workings of a Hazelcast Jet Vertex?

Tags: java, directed-acyclic-graphs, hazelcast-jet

I'm trying to rework a hazelcast Jet 0.3 DAG system I wrote a few weeks ago into v0.4 as a first step of changing it from batch to stream. Interestingly all of a sudden I'm experiencing some weird behavior, where I can't be sure that vertices work as expected. Trying to get down on what's happening, I fail to find an option on how to peek into the the inner workings of each vertex. Is there a way to get at least some error messages out of them?

In an attempt to isolate the problem I tried to dumb it down to a very simplistic "read from list, map it to a map write to map" DAG. But still no success on getting anything out.

Below my dumbed down example, maybe I make a very simple mistake that someone more knowledgable will see right away?

**Publisher:**

```
// every second via executorservice:
final IStreamMap<Long, List<byte[]>> data = jet.getMap("data");
data.set(jet.getHazelcastInstance().getAtomicLong("key").getAndIncrement(), myByteArray);
```

**Analyzer:**

```
jet.getList(key.toString()).addAll((List<byte[]>) jet.getMap("data").get(key));
jet.getMap("data").remove(key);
logger.debug("List {} has size: {}", key, jet.getList(key.toString()).size());

final Vertex sourceDataMap = this.newVertex("sourceDataMap", readList(key.toString())).localParallelism(1);
final Vertex parseByteArrayToMap = this.newVertex("parseByteArrayToMap", map(
    (byte[] e) ->  new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(jet.getHazelcastInstance().getAtomicLong("counter").getAndIncrement(), e)));
final Vertex sinkIntoResultMap = this.newVertex("sinkIntoResultMap", writeMap("result"));

this.edge(between(sourceDataMap, parseByteArrayToMap))
    .edge(between(parseByteArrayToMap,  sinkIntoResultMap));
```

**Listener:**

```
jet.getMap("result").addEntryListener((EntryAddedListener<Long, byte[]>)
       (EntryEvent<Long, byte[]> entryEvent)
           -> logger.debug("Got result: {} at {}",entryEvent.getValue().length, System.currentTimeMillis())
       , true);
```

The data generation works just fine, everything is ok till the DAG should take over... but no error messages or anything coming from the DAG. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can demonstrate your problem? And you can also check the `DiagnosticProcessors` class that has the tools you describe.

Comment: You have a lambda which refers to `jet`. The JetInstance ins't serializable, so can't be used as part of the lambda. If you want to generate unique IDs, you can use something like `UUID.randomUUID()`.

Comment: I tried to execute a job from the DAG you posted and it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` at the line that creates the vertex Can mentions.   So it fails fast (and loud), before even getting the opportunity to start a job.

Comment: ...and after changing to `randomUUID()`, i get the entry listener's log output.

Comment: OK that's weird, I didn't get that IllegalArgumentException. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: And found the reason why I didn't get the error. Double executioner wrapping. Read runnable in runnable -> outer runnable eats inner errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code slightly sanitized that works on my side:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JetInstance jet = Jet.newJetInstance();
        try {
            HazelcastInstance hz = jet.getHazelcastInstance();
            ILogger logger = hz.getLoggingService().getLogger("a");

            // every second via executorservice:
            final IStreamMap<Long, List<byte[]>> data = jet.getMap("data");
            List<byte[]> myByteArray = asList(new byte[1], new byte[2]);
            IAtomicLong keyGen = hz.getAtomicLong("key");
            Long key = keyGen.getAndIncrement();
            data.set(key, myByteArray);

            String stringKey = key.toString();
            hz.getList(stringKey).addAll((List<byte[]>) jet.getMap("data").get(key));
            jet.getMap("data").remove(key);
            logger.severe(String.format("List %s has size: %d", key, jet.getList(stringKey).size()));

            hz.getMap("result").addEntryListener((EntryAddedListener<Long, byte[]>)
                    (EntryEvent<Long, byte[]> entryEvent) -> logger.severe(String.format(
                            "Got result: %d at %d", entryEvent.getValue().length, System.currentTimeMillis())),
                    true);

            DAG dag = new DAG();
            Vertex sourceDataMap = dag.newVertex("sourceDataMap", readList(stringKey)).localParallelism(1);
            Vertex parseByteArrayToMap = dag.newVertex("parseByteArrayToMap", map(
                    (byte[] e) -> entry(randomUUID(), e)));
            Vertex sinkIntoResultMap = dag.newVertex("sinkIntoResultMap", writeMap("result"));

            dag.edge(between(sourceDataMap, parseByteArrayToMap))
               .edge(between(parseByteArrayToMap, sinkIntoResultMap));

            jet.newJob(dag).execute().get();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } finally {
            Jet.shutdownAll();
        }
    }
}
```

In the console i see:

```
SEVERE: [192.168.5.12]:5701 [jet] [0.4-SNAPSHOT] [3.8.2] List 0 has size: 2
SEVERE: [192.168.5.12]:5701 [jet] [0.4-SNAPSHOT] [3.8.2] Got result: 2 at 1498822322228
SEVERE: [192.168.5.12]:5701 [jet] [0.4-SNAPSHOT] [3.8.2] Got result: 1 at 1498822322228
```